# Can you identify this DIODE or its logo?

Tags: diodes, identification

Can you identify this diode or its logo? I'm hoping to at least learn who manufactured it to narrow my search.

[image]

Comment: The logo looks somewhat like the Harris Semiconductor logo. They were later renamed as Intersil, and just recently changed their name to Renesas Electronics.

Comment: I've not seen that wide H logo in any searchies for Harris Semiconductor,

Comment: To me, it looks like a sideways (capital) letter  i

Answer (score 9):

Searching for "2020R Diode" shows several options, such as [On-Semi MUR**2020R**](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MUR2020R-D.PDF) in the correct TO-220 package.

This may not be the exact manufacturer, but it will likely be a compatible alternative. There are many series numbers that are made by multiple manufacturers, including unnamed fab houses.

Comment: I came across the same results. I was hoping to remove any uncertainty by finding the chips original spec since I wasn't sure if that was a coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the logo I'd guess it's most probably from a Chinese semiconductor fab called Hanking Electronics.

Their main logo is slightly different, but the H part is a pretty good match.  I tried to find some examples of smaller package products from them, but yeaaah.  Good luck finding a supplier, I can't. Seems like these days they're all about the MEMS.

https://www.linkedin.com/company/hanking-electronics-ltd./

Comment: I think you're probably right. I was hoping to find the spec to ensure I get a compatible replacement but they only do MEMS. Their site doesn't even mention diodes anywhere so not sure if they manufacture it. Hard to know since can't find any small parts by them to see if they use the H on their other parts.

Comment: @randomName I suspect they changed business focus, I tried looking for a supplier that carries their parts but it just loops back to more press releases.